# Form based membership in sharepoint 2007 , facing issue?

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication

I had followed the exact steps to configure form authentication in shrepoint 2007 from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/FBA.aspx) but i am unable to login with the user. I checked that my connection string is right, providers are also current so what should be the issue ?

I have another question regarding same topic.let say i have configured the membership database in my sql server database by using the asp.net configuration application.

say I have created a user "XYZ". certainly this will inserted into the membership database. but, will this user ("XYZ") also added in Active directory users ? or not.

If not then while creating the user in sharepoint site (from people and group) How it will resolve the "XYZ" user which i entered in membership database?

because as i explained i have created user "lalit" from asp.net configuration database , i found this user in membership database. where as i have given connection string to that site, of my membership database. and when I went to add new user for the site through People and group option (from site settings) , I got error message "No user match found" something like this. So i created user in active directory with name " lalit" then it resolved. but why should i need to create the "lalit" as user to active directory ? Or why then need to create the membership database if active directory users are there ...?

Comment: i am also facing exact same problem with my server.

Comment: please help ....me...help me pleaase.....!

Comment: post your question here : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the provider as a prefix, for example, if your provider membership name is MOSSProvider, when you add a user to a group, you have to add it as "MOSSProvider:username", also you must have configured your site with FAB. Check Alternate Access Mapping operation for doing that.